# Change appid in Ionic1

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to install a second version (keeping the first one) of an app I'm developing on an android device.
So I have to change the appid of the application.

I changed the widget id in **config.xml**
and then

```
cordova platform add android
cordova platform add android
```

when I launch `ionic cordova run android --livereload` I get

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]
```

like I'm trying to update the first app. How can I be sure to install a new app?

Answer (score 0):

To install 2 ionic apps in your terninal you should change the aplication id in the file config.xml.
If you try to install 2 aplications whit the same id you will get an error.

By default is:

```
    <widget id="io.ionic.starter"
```

You shoud not changue anything more.